# Place mode with API v3 (without embed)

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to get that exact result:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#place_mode
(without details box, only pointer on map with place icon) but using Google Maps API Web Services v3 and not embed api?